# Using Bootstrap when I reduce the size of the screen the components move and eventually move out of format

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I'm writing my first website using Bootstrap and CSS style sheets with VS2015 and it all lines up perfectly when in full max screen. However, when I start to reduce the size of the screen, instead of the scroll bars taking over, the components move and eventually all fall out of line.
Below is how I have set out my html screen

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Strict//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <!--Bootstrap-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet1.css" />

</head>
```

How can I set my components to fixed and just allow the scrolling whatever size of the browser?

I have spent quite a bit of time browsing on this and I've experimented with @media and other CSS changes but nothing works.

Comment: Please, post your jsfiddle, css and etc

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for this (which I don't recommend):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Here is an article: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/viewport-meta-tag-for-non-responsive-design

You can also try placing min-width onto your outermost container, like this:

```
#your-main-page-wrapper-around-everything { min-width: 1200px; }
```

Bootstrap CSS is intended to be responsive, so your other option is to study their grid css:  http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid
This would give you control over how the columns will wrap, so you won't have to prevent user scaling.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The solution definitely lies in the area you have outlined but I tried both suggestions and the page is still re-positioning components when reducing the width.

Comment: If you place a wrapper around the entire page, and set a fixed width on it, your components should stay still.  https://jsfiddle.net/7udtfz62/